# How to handle multiple parallel requests in FastAPI for an ML model API

Tags: machine-learning, python-asyncio, fastapi

I have built an ML model API using FastAPI, and this API mostly requires GPU usage. I want to make this API serve at least some amount of parallel requests. To achieve this, I tried to make all the functions def instead of async def so that it can handle requests concurrently (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516140/fastapi-runs-api-calls-in-serial-instead-of-parallel-fashion/71517830#71517830:%7E:text=Async/await%20and%20Blocking%20I/O%2Dbound%20or%20CPU%2Dbound%20Operations), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71186596/how-to-avoid-duplicate-processing-in-python-apiserver/71188190#71188190:%7E:text=Thus%2C%20when%20you%20use%20def%20instead%20of%20async%20def%20the%20server%20processes%20requests%20concurrently.) and [here](https://youtu.be/nvLRjtvu1nk?t=1697)). Currently, what I am experiencing is that if one request is made, it takes 3 seconds to get output, and if three parallel requests are made, then all users are getting the output in 9 seconds. Here, all users are getting the output at the same time, but as you can see, the time increases as the number of requests increases. However, what I actually want is for all users to get the output in 3 seconds.

I have tried some approaches like ThreadPoolExecutor ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516140/fastapi-runs-api-calls-in-serial-instead-of-parallel-fashion/71517830#71517830:%7E:text=loop%20%3D%20asyncio.get_running_loop()%0Awith%20concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()%20as%20pool%3A%0A%20%20%20%20res%20%3D%20await%20loop.run_in_executor(pool%2C%20cpu_bound_task%2C%20contents))), ProcessPoolExecutor ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71613305/how-to-process-requests-from-multiiple-users-using-ml-model-and-fastapi#:%7E:text=Alternatively%2C%20as%20described)), Asyncio ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516140/fastapi-runs-api-calls-in-serial-instead-of-parallel-fashion/71517830#71517830:%7E:text=import%20asyncio%0A%0Ares%20%3D%20await%20asyncio.to_thread(cpu_bound_task%2C%20contents))), run_in_threadpool ([here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1066#issuecomment-612940187)), but none of these methods worked for me.

This is the how my api code looks like with simple def:

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, File, UploadFile, Response
import uvicorn

class Model_loading():
    def __init__():
        self.model = torch.load('model.pth')


app = Fastapi()
model_instance = Model_loading()

def gpu_based_processing(x):

   ---- doing some gpu based computation ----

   return result


@app.post('/model-testing')
def my_function(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    
   ---- doing some initial preprocessing ----

   output = gpu_based_processing(x)

   return Response(content=output , media_type="image/jpg")
```

Additionally, I have observed a behavior where making 20 parallel requests to the above API leads to a CUDA out-of-memory error. Even with only 20 requests, it is unable to handle them. How can I address the CUDA memory issue and manage handling multiple parallel requests simultaneously?

Comment: When you only have one request, how much GPU resources does that use? If `pytorch` is efficient and uses (close to) 100% GPU, then that's the limiting factor, and running more concurrent computations will simply make all of them take longer.